# Cisco session time issue

Tags: cisco

I have a network with 3 cisco catalyst  3500.  When I move my computer from one of cisco  ethernet ports      to another ethernet  port of the same cisco or from one cisco switch to another cisco switch. I have to wait for a long period,  For example 10 mins,  to be able to connect to  internet. 
Is there any configuration of Cisco that needs to be modified to reduced this time delay.

Regards,
Andre

Comment: Can you share any of the configuration on the interfaces?  And can you test to see what the exact time is between changing switch interfaces and having connectivity (internal as well as internet)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can issue a command that will flush the ARP cache in the switch to speed the transition time up a little bit.   I believe you can even delete a particular MAC entry as well.  There may very well be a ARP cache timeout setting too that would help you out in this particular situation.

Comment: The ARP cache has nothing to do with it. ARP resolves ip addresses to MAC addresses, which is not what the switch does (unless the switch itself is communicating with the endpoint, but even if it was it wouldn't cause this problem). What the OP needs to look at is the MAC address table cache settings. The default MAC address table aging time on a Catalyst 3500 series switch should be 300 seconds (5 minutes).

Comment: I have done this before, but apparently got the wrong table name.

Answer (score 0):

The ARP cache has nothing to do with it. ARP resolves ip addresses to MAC addresses, which is not what the switch does (unless the switch itself is communicating with the endpoint, but even if it was it wouldn't cause this problem). What you need to look at is the MAC address table cache settings. The default MAC address table aging time on a Catalyst 3500 series switch should be 300 seconds (5 minutes).

Comment: I also think that is MAC ADDRESS table aging time issue. I will look for the related  command  and try to make the modification. If you know the command please help me on that too.

Comment: Why would you want to modify it? It's set to that default setting for a reason. My answer was to simply tell you what was causing the problem, not to suggest that you change it.